# gcc reports "will never be executed" about the line: while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE, stdin) != NULL)

Tags: c, cygwin, warnings, gcc3, unreachable-code

I'm looking for an explanation why `gcc` are giving this warning for me.

I'm compiling with the `gcc-3` on `cygwin` with the `-Wunreachable-code` flag, and the gcc says this warning for me:

> main.c:223: warning: will never be executed

That's this line: `while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE, stdin) != NULL) {`

This code is inside a `if(exp) { }` block where `exp` is dynamically set according to command-line-arguments(parsed by `getopt()` ), look at the code part:

```
 if(mystruct.hastab) {
```

the default value is `0`. But it's become `1` if `-t` flag is passed to application, as you can see at following:

```
struct mystruct_t {
   //... 
   int hastab;
} mystruct;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

      int opt;
        memset(&mystruct, 0, sizeof(mystruct));
         while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optString)) != -1) {
            switch(opt) {
              case 't':
               mystruct.hastab = 1;
               break;
              //....
            }
        }
         proc();
        return 0;
    }

    void 
    proc(void)
    {
      char *buf, *tmpbuf, line[MAX_LINE + 1], *p, *fullfilename;

      if(mystruct.hastab) {

        while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE, stdin) != NULL) {
           //...
        }
      } else {
       //...
      }
    }
```

So, there's a reason for the code be executed. As happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another possibility: the problem is with macros.  Here's a simple example that demonstrates your error:

```
#include <string.h>
int s;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  memset(&s, 0, sizeof(s));
}
```

When I compile this, I get:

```
$ gcc -Wunreachable-code tmp.c
tmp.c: In function ‘main’:
tmp.c:4: warning: will never be executed
```

The error is not particularly enlightening.  However, if you run the preprocessor, look what `memset` expands to:

```
$ gcc -E tmp.c

...
int s;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  ((__builtin_object_size (&s, 0) != (size_t) -1) ? __builtin___memset_chk (&s, 0, sizeof(s), __builtin_object_size (&s, 0)) : __inline_memset_chk (&s, 0, sizeof(s)));
}
```

I suspect because of the constant size of `s`, only one of the branches of the `?:` is ever executed, and this is what gcc is complaining about.  In your case, it's probably that `fgets` is a macro.  Run `gcc -E`, find your problem line in the output, and see if it's wonky (mine isn't, but I'm not running cygwin).

Moral of the story: preprocessors & macros suck.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like gcc is convinced `hastab` is never set, or that it is only set after the code it's warning about.  It certainly seems like gcc is wrong, but since you only gave us snippets it is hard to be sure.  I don't think anyone can help you further unless we see a complete program we can compile ourselves.

Comment: It's rarely that gcc is wrong.  It's most likely that the code snippets aren't giving the complete story.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: I call too in main function before first while-loop: `memset(&mystruct, 0, sizeof(mystruct));`.  `if(mystruct.hastab) {` is called in other function, that's called in main. `mystruct` is a global variable. I didn't posted before in because I think this information useless. It's complete story.

Comment: @PaulTomblin: Check out the update. How my `main` function works and a significant part of `proc` function. I removed only the statements inside the blocks.

Comment: Slap it in a debugger and see what `mystruct.hastab` contains on entry to `proc()`.  Chances are it's not what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess I'd say gcc is considering that there are 2 cases where you can call `proc()` without having set `mystruct.hastab` to something other than `0`.

The first case is if this evaulates to `false` on the first run through, since you will drop out of the loop without executing your `switch` statement:

`while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optString)) != -1) {`

The second case is if `opt` is never `'t'`:

```
switch(opt) {
case 't':
    mystruct.hastab = 1;
```

So you will fall out of the loop without ever having set `mystruct.hastab` to a non-zero value.